# Trigger a report based entry of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, triggers, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using `MS SQL Server 2008R2` Standard Edition. I'm looking to trigger a report based on end entry of an end value into a certain table. The report was designed using `SQL Server Business Intelligence` Development studio.

Is it possible to do this without using data driven subscriptions. Data driven subscriptions are a feature missing from Standard Edition of `MS SQL Server 2008R2`.

I have a partial solution

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Report_INSERT_PHASE_PROC

ON [database].[dbo].[table] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [database].[dbo].[table] where process_value = 'End Of BATCH' )
BEGIN 

    EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription',

    @EventData='xxxx' -- SubscriptionID from Report Manager URL 
END 
go
```

But this is triggering on on every insert and my table has historical process_value = 'End of Batch'. So I need to add an AND if serial_no = inserted serial_no to my condition.

How could I find the value of the inserted serial number?

Comment: How you are entering the data in the table?

Comment: @AnupAgrawal the data is being entered in a via VBA in a format over which I have no control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a bit column to the table called 'processed'.  Then update the procedure to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Report_INSERT_PHASE_PROC
ON [database].[dbo].[table] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
IF EXISTS (
           SELECT * 
           FROM [database].[dbo].[table] 
           WHERE process_value = 'End Of BATCH' 
                AND processed = 0 -- Only process if there is an unprocessed record
          )
BEGIN 

    EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription',
    @EventData='xxxx' -- SubscriptionID from Report Manager URL 

    -- Mark record as processed
    UPDATE [database].[dbo].[table] 
    SET processed = 1 
    WHERE process_value = 'End Of BATCH' 
         AND processed = 0

END 
go
```

Comment: That probably would work but I have to see if the column can be added to table as I have no control over the database structure, only the reporting services.

Comment: Is there an auto-incremented PK in the table?  If so you could update the SELECT query's WHERE clause to: WHERE process_value = 'End Of BATCH' AND (SELECT MAX([primary_key]) FROM [table]) = [primary_key]

Comment: I've it pretty much working now with your query providing the sketch of what to do. I had to add a processed table not a row. I also had to add in a wait for delay of 10 secs between exec and update. The report looks for the last unprocessed batch. Without the delay the records were mark processed before report had been published. Is there any way around this issue or to at least minimize that delay somewhat?

Comment: Can you change the report to look for the last processed batch?